# Proving a compact Lie group admits a biinvariant metric

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

At the end of a lesson in Differential Geometry, my teacher said:

> Fatto, che non dimostriamo, non è difficile ma il tempo scarseggia, se $G$ è compatto possiamo sempre trovare una metrica Riemanniana biinvariante su $G$, d'accordo? Tuttavia non è vero che $\varphi$, $\varphi$ invariante a sinistra non implica, d'accordo, non implica invariante a destra, cioè è possibile, lo faremo la prossima volta ormai, costruire metriche invarianti a sinistra ma non a destra.

That is:

> A fact which we won't prove, it's not difficult but time is scarce, if [a Lie group] $G$ is compact we can always find a biinvariant Riemannian metric on $G$, OK? However it is not true that $\varphi$, $\varphi$ left-invariant doesn't imply, OK, doesn't imply right-invariant, that is it is possible, we will do it next time by now, to build left-invariant but not right-invariant metrics.

I must admit I have no clue how to use compactness to construct such a metric. I tried Googling, but I basically only found [this](http://idv.sinica.edu.tw/ftliang/diff_geom/*diff_geometry%28II%29/4.08/lie_group_curvature.pdf), and the exponential map is at the end of the course, so if he says "it is not difficult" in a lesson which is barely halfway through the course it must not be strictly necessary to use that map. I found what $\mathrm{Ad}$ is, so I know that $\mathrm{Ad}(g)$ is the differential at the identity of the conjugation map $\Psi_g(h)=ghg^{-1}$:

$$\mathrm{Ad}(g)=\mathrm{d}_e\Psi_g.$$

So how can I prove this fact? Is it possible *not* to mention the exponential map?

**Update 2**

After reading [this](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2010/REUPapers/Gleason.pdf), I have access to Haar measures. I also know how to construct a left-invariant metric on a Lie group, even a noncompact one. So how do I reformulate the metric given in the suggested duplicate in terms of the Haar measure and prove it is bi-invariant?

**Update 3**

Following Daniel's comments, I tried proving the metric he suggested:

$$(u,v)_g=\int\limits_G\langle\mathrm{d}_gR_hu,\mathrm{d}_gR_hv\rangle_{gh}\mathrm{d}\mu(h),$$

for any $u,v\in T_gG$, is a bi-invariant metric. I started with left-invariance, and got stuck. Here is my try. Now left-invariance means that for any $k\in G$, $L_k^\ast(\cdot,\cdot)=(\cdot,\cdot)$. In other words, for any $g,k\in G,u,v\in T_gG$, we must have:

$$(u,v)_g=(\mathrm{d}_gL_ku,\mathrm{d}_gL_ku)_{kg}.$$

By the definition of our metric, this means the following two integrals must be equal:

$$\int\limits_G\langle\mathrm{d}_gR_hu,\mathrm{d}_gR_hv\rangle_{gh}\mathrm{d}\mu(h)=\int\limits_G\langle\mathrm{d}_{kg}R_h\mathrm{d}_gL_ku,\mathrm{d}_{kg}R_h\mathrm{d}_gL_kv\rangle_{kgh}\mathrm{d}\mu(h).$$

At this point I should exploit that we built $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ as a left-invariant metric. So I tried viewing that integrand as a pullback, but I got the pullback via $L_k$ of the pullback via $R_h$ of the metric, evalued at $g$, on the original vectors $u,v$. I wish I could eliminate the pullback via $L_k$, but I'd need it to be on the inside to exploit the left-invariance. I do not know if the pullback via $R_h$ of the metric is still left-invariant. I also tried changing variables to exploit the left-invariance of the measure. So setting $\ell=kg$ I got an integrand of $\langle\mathrm{d}_\ell R_h\mathrm{d}_{k^{-1}\ell}L_ku,\mathrm{d}_\ell R_h\mathrm{d}_gL_{\ell g^{-1}}v\rangle_{\ell h}\mathrm{d}\mu(h)$. Notice how I treated the two things in the metric differently to show two possible ways of making the change, writing $g$ in terms of $k,\ell$ on the left and $k$ in terms of $g,\ell$ on the right. But I have two problems: one, the measure is the same, so I cannot exploit its invariance property, and two, the integrand looks worse than before. So how do I proceed here?

That said, right-invariance can indeed be proved as in [that answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/105494/135592). Let me read it carefully.

**Update 4**

$\newcommand{\diff}{\mathrm{d}}$
I think I have proved right-invariance, which decidedly makes this question a NON-DUPLICATE. Here is what I did:

\begin{align*}
(\diff_gR_ku,\diff_gR_kv)_{gk}={}&\int\limits_G\langle\diff_{gk}R_h\diff_gR_ku,\diff_{gk}R_h\diff_gR_kv\rangle_{gkh}\diff\mu(h)={} \\
{}={}&\int\limits_G\langle\diff_g(R_h\circ R_k)u,\diff_g(R_h\circ R_k)v\rangle_{gkh}\diff\mu(h)={} \\
{}={}&\int\limits_G\langle\diff_gR_{kh}u,\diff_gR_{kh}v\rangle_{gkh}\diff\mu(h)={} \\
{}={}&\int\limits_G\langle\diff_gR_\ell u,\diff_gR_\ell v\rangle_{g\ell}\diff\mu(k^{-1}\ell)={} \\
{}={}&\int\limits_G\langle\diff_gR_\ell u,\diff_gR_\ell v\rangle_{g\ell}\diff\mu(\ell)=(u,v)_g.
\end{align*}

Steps thus justified:

1. Definition of the metric.
2. $\diff_g(R_h\circ R_k)=\diff_{R_kg}R_h\circ\diff_gR_k=\diff_{gk}R_h\circ\diff_gR_k$ by the chain rule.
3. $R_h\circ R_k=R_{kh}$.
4. Set $\ell=kg$ and change variables. $h=k^{-1}\ell$.
5. This is where I use the invariance. I used it in the form $\diff\mu(k^{-1}\ell)=\diff\mu(L_{k^{-1}}\ell)=\diff\mu(\ell)$. Is that right?
6. Definition of the metric again.

So if the above are correct, the point of the other question is solved, and if they aren't, then the reason why they aren't should be explained here, making this decidedly NOT a duplicate of that one, as it never really was IMHO.

(For those wishing to delve deeper in the history of this post and its later exact duplicate, here are [the first update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYcie.png), [the link in that update](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72333/compact-lie-group-bi-invariant-metric) and the [note on the duplicate issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwIgV.png), which were removed as non-mathematical clutter)

Comment: Are you familiar with Haar measures? If so, you can just replace the "left invariant positive differential $n$-form $\omega$" with the Haar measure $\mu$ on $G$ over there.

Comment: @DanielFischer nope, never seen Haar measures. Only saw the name in books' indexes :).

Comment: :( Then I guess it's not so easy. It's easy to get left-invariant _or_ right-invariant Riemannian metrics, but for a bi-invariant one, I don't know of a way to construct it that doesn't require integration wrt the Haar measure/an invariant volume form.

Comment: After reading [this](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2010/REUPapers/Gleason.pdf) I have a minimum familiarity with Haar measures, in particular knowing a left Haar measure always exists on a locally compact topological group, hence on any Lie group.

Comment: @DanielFischer how do I proceed?

Comment: You take any inner product $\langle\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,\rangle_e$ on $T_e G$. From that you construct a left-invariant Riemannian metric by defining $\langle X_g, Y_g\rangle_g = \langle (dL_g(e))^{-1}X_g, (dL_g(e))^{-1}Y_g\rangle_e$, where $L_g \colon x \mapsto gx$ is the left translation. With that left-invariant Riemannian metric, you get the bi-invariant metric by averaging, $$(X_g,Y_g)_g = \int_G \langle dR_h(g) X_g, dR_h(g)Y_g\rangle_{gh}\,d\mu(h),$$ where $R_h\colon x \mapsto xh$ is the right translation by $h$, and $\mu$ is the (left) Haar measure on $G$.

Comment: And seeing the proof of existence of a left Haar measure I completely agree: it is NOT easy :). And it needs things from outside the course.

Comment: Note that the existence of a Haar measure on a compact topological group is easier to prove, it's theorem 5.14 in Rudin's _Functional Analysis_. It is also proved there that on compact topological groups, a left Haar measure is also right-invariant.

Comment: @Daniel I'm having a hard time proving that is left-invariant. But let us continue tomorrow, I have to go now.

Comment: I'll be gone for a couple of days from tomorrow on, so it'll have to wait a bit longer. Until Wednesday or so, probably.

Comment: Darn :(. Well tomorrow I will add what I've tried to the Q and then I'll continue going over the notes from that course as I wait for your comeback (or someone else's answer) :). Good day to you.

Comment: [Moved this problem elsewhere](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658705/proving-left-invariance-and-proof-verification-for-right-invariance-for-metric).

Comment: @user153330 Huh again :).