# Proving left-invariance (and proof-verification for right-invariance) for metric constructed from left-invariant Haar measure

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

$\newcommand{\diff}{\mathrm{d}}$
**TL;DR**

1. Having read [this](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2010/REUPapers/Gleason.pdf) I know something about Haar measures, in particular that a left-invariant one exists and is unique on any Lie group $G$.
2. I know that defining:

   $$\langle x,y\rangle_g=\langle(\mathrm{d}_gL_g)^{-1}(x),(\mathrm{d}_gL_g)^{-1}(y)\rangle,$$

   where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is any inner product on the Lie algebra $T_eG$ and $L_g$ is the map $L_g(h)=gh$, one obtains a left-invariant metric for $G$.
3. I know that if $G$ is compact we can define the metric:

   $$(u,v)_g=\int\limits_G\langle\diff_gR_h(u),\diff_gR_h(v)\rangle_{gh}\diff\mu(h),$$

   where $\mu$ is the unique left-invariant Haar measure on $G$;
4. I believe the following proves right-invariance for that metric:

   > \begin{align*}
   > (\diff_gR_ku,\diff_gR_kv)_{gk}={}&\int\limits_G\langle\diff_{gk}R_h\diff_gR_ku,\diff_{gk}R_h\diff_gR_kv\rangle_{gkh}\diff\mu(h)={} \\
   > {}={}&\int\limits_G\langle\diff_g(R_h\circ R_k)u,\diff_g(R_h\circ R_k)v\rangle_{gkh}\diff\mu(h)={} \\
   > {}={}&\int\limits_G\langle\diff_gR_{kh}u,\diff_gR_{kh}v\rangle_{gkh}\diff\mu(h)=\int\limits_G\langle\diff_gR_\ell u,\diff_gR_\ell v\rangle_{g\ell}\diff\mu(k^{-1}\ell)={} \\
   > {}={}&\int\limits_G\langle\diff_gR_\ell u,\diff_gR_\ell v\rangle_{g\ell}\diff\mu(\ell)=(u,v)_g.
   > \end{align*}
   >
   > Steps thus justified:
   >
   > 1. Definition of the metric.
   > 2. $\diff_g(R_h\circ R_k)=\diff_{R_kg}R_h\circ\diff_gR_k=\diff_{gk}R_h\circ\diff_gR_k$ by the chain rule.
   > 3. $R_h\circ R_k=R_{kh}$.
   > 4. Set $\ell=kg$ and change variables. $h=k^{-1}\ell$.
   > 5. This is where I use the invariance. I used it in the form $\diff\mu(k^{-1}\ell)=\diff\mu(L_{k^{-1}}\ell)=\diff\mu(\ell)$. Is that right?
   > 6. Definition of the metric again.

So my question is: is the proof in 4. correct? And how do I prove left-invariance?

(For those wishing to delve deeper into the history of this post and its earlier exact duplicate, see edit history)

Comment: You need to assume $G$ is compact, or else the integral in step 3 will not be finite.

Comment: Whoops I forgot about that.

Comment: @JackLee And compactness ensures finiteness because ...? The integrand is bounded and that, on a compact set, implies integrability, perhaps? How do I prove this boundedness?

Comment: The integrand is continuous. Every continuous function on a compact space is bounded and integrable.

Comment: Your proof in 4. is correct. For left invariance, start with $(d_g L_k u, d_g L_k v)_{kg}$, use the fact that $L_k \circ R_h = R_h \circ L_k$ and the left-invariance of $\langle\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,\rangle$.

Comment: @Daniel I guess I was missing that composition thing. Will do the "dirty work" tomorrow. And ask another question concerning the continuity (thinking on it, perhaps even smoothness, I daresay) of that integrand.

Comment: In fact, all I needed was to look at update 3 while thinking of this commutation property to mentally conclude the calcs.

Comment: Goodnight and thks to all and I'll be back tomorrow for that continuity thing :).

Comment: So to finish this question off, we have to decide who converts the comments to an answer. Do I self-answer and get the rep from possible upvotes, or do you answer and get the rep you deserve for helping me, @Daniel? You choose.

Comment: Me very lazy now ;)

Comment: Perhaps you can post a near-blank answer and then I can fill in the blank, so I write the stuff and you don't have to rewrite it but still get the rep :)?

Comment: If you're afraid of rep, you can make the answer CW :)

Comment: It's not that much about getting the rep, but rather about taking it away from the rightful owner of it, i.e. you. But if you do not care, I will just self-answer :). Besides, I am aiming for 3k, so some more rep would do me good :).

Comment: PS [Continuity issue moved here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1659695/proving-continuity-smoothness-for-a-special-function-on-a-lie-group).

Comment: I asked you to do remove non-mathematical stuff such as speculation about which variant is a duplicate of which. Nicely :-(

Comment: And I will @Jyrki. Tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\diff}{\mathrm{d}}$
Converting [@Daniel's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658705/proving-left-invariance-and-proof-verification-for-right-invariance-for-metric?noredirect=1#comment3383611_1658705) to an answer to get this question answered.

The proof of 4 is, he says, correct.

As for left-invariance, I merely have to exploit the fact that $L_g\circ R_k=R_k\circ L_g$, and do the following:

\begin{align*}
(\diff_gL_ku,\diff_gL_kv)_{kg}={}&\int\limits_G\langle\diff_{gk}R_h\diff_gL_ku,\diff_{gk}R_h\diff_gL_kv\rangle_{kgh}\diff\mu(h)={} \\
{}={}&\int\limits_G\langle\diff_g(R_h\circ L_k)u,\diff_g(R_h\circ L_k)v\rangle_{kgh}\diff\mu(h)={} \\
{}={}&\int\limits_G\langle\diff_g(L_k\circ R_h)u,\diff_g(L_k\circ R_h)v\rangle_{kgh}\diff\mu(h)={} \\
{}={}&\int\limits_G\langle\diff_{gh}L_k\diff_gR_hu,\diff_{gh}L_k\diff_gR_hv\rangle_{kgh}\diff\mu(h)={} \\
{}={}&\int\limits_G\langle\diff_gR_hu,\diff_gR_hv\rangle_{gh}\diff\mu(h)=(u,v)_g.
\end{align*}

The elimination of $\diff_{gh}L_k$ was done thanks to left-invariance of $\langle\cdot,\cdot,\rangle$. That this be "positive definite" is obvious, since the integrand will be strictly positive on the whole of $G$. As proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1659695/proving-continuity-smoothness-for-a-special-function-on-a-lie-group), or with similar arguments, if I plug in smooth fields I get smooth functions in the integrand, and the integral of a smooth function is smooth. So this is indeed a biinvariant metric. Of course, this requires the integral to converge, which is guaranteed by the compactness, but it is not strictly required that the group be compact.

Comment: please revise your latex it doesn't seem to work (\diff doesn't show up correctly)

Comment: @user153330 Huh? I see a bunch of perfectly fine $\mathrm{d}$s where I guess you see \diff's…

Comment: that's weird, can u ask someone else in the chat to check in for verification purposes?

Comment: @user153330 Yes I can. Might I suggest you take the time to type meaningful edit summaries? I just reviewed two edits of yours, one had a meaningless edit summary made of LaTeX commands and the other one had a paragraph of the edited post (deprived of the links) as the edit summary. That is not really that good :).

Comment: @user153330 [here is the chat where I asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39463/mathjax-rendering-weirdoes).

Comment: lol i'm too focused on the actual editing rather than the edit summary plus i'm too laze to type 'transforming the image into latex commands'

Comment: What about "copied the picture"? Half as long :). Or what about no summary at all? At least it will be "Added … characters in the body", which makes sense :).

Comment: no summary? i'm always asked to type at least 10 characters or so in the edit summary

Comment: @user153330 Wow that's about as weird as the MathJax thing. Usually, if I type nothing, it just auto-adds "Added … characters in the body", where … is a number.

Comment: Then again, maybe I am misremembering, since I don't do that very often :).

Comment: that's because you have more than 2000 in your rep

Comment: Oh. Didn't know that @user153330 :). OK no matter. But "copied picture" is pretty short anyway :).