# Riemannian distance function on Lie group that is right $G$ invariant and left $K$-invariant for maximal compact subgroup $K$ in $G$

Tags: riemannian-geometry, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a connected semisimple Lie group and $K$ be a maximal compact subgroup of $G$. I  mostly care about the case where $G=\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)$ and $K=\text{SO}(d,\mathbb R)$.

> I wonder how to construct a Riemannian distant function $dist$ on $G$ such that it is right $G$-invariant and left $K$-invariant. That is for $k\in K$ and $g'\in G$,
> $$dist(g,h)=dist(kg,kh), dist(gg',hg')=dist(g,h) \tag{*}$$

Canonically, one could start by defining an inner product $\langle ~,~ \rangle_e$ on the Lie algebra $T_e G$ and define the inner product on $T_g G$ by
$$\langle u,v \rangle_g := \langle (dR_{g^{-1}})_g u, (dR_{g^{-1}})_g v\rangle_e$$

For the special case that $G=\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)$ and $K=\text{SO}(d,\mathbb R)$, *naively* it looks as if the orthogonal matrices preserves inner product: $\langle ku,kv \rangle_g = \langle u,v \rangle_g$ for any $k\in K=\text{SO}(d,\mathbb R)$ but I don't know why this makes sense since we are acting the Lie subgroup $K$ on the tangent space (it should act on group elements not the vectors) and it looks quite unrelated to $(*)$. Also, this doesn't generalize to the general $G,K$ above.

---

Relevant questions for the case when $G$ itself is compact are

[Compact Lie group bi-invariant metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72333/compact-lie-group-bi-invariant-metric?rq=1)

[Proving left-invariance (and proof-verification for right-invariance) for metric constructed from left-invariant Haar measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658705/proving-left-invariance-and-proof-verification-for-right-invariance-for-metric)

I believe some modifications based on these might solve my question.

Comment: You should not call $dist$ a Riemannian metric (which is a tensor on a manifold); you can call it a Riemannian distance function. As for a hint: First construct a Riemannian metric (tensor) which is $G$-left-invariant and $K$-right-invariant (by averaging).

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you! Just corrected it.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Can you explain a little more about the word averaging? Averaging over what?

Comment: Integrate over $K$ using its invariant volume form.